# Using Joi to override param value

Tags: javascript, joi

I'm using Joi to validate params for a function that has the purpose to create pagination metadata. The function receives the following params `totalItemsNum`, `skip`, and `limit`. I'm trying to achieve the following scenario:

1 - When `totalItemsNum` is equal to 0, Joi should set the value of the `skip` param to zero regardless of the original value.

2 - When `totalItemsNum` is not zero, Joi should not let the `skip` param be equal or greater than `totalItemsNum`. So if `skip` is equal or greater than `totalItemsNum`, Joi should set the value of the `skip` param to `totalItemsNum` - 1.

I manage to achieve that with the following code:

```
  const validator = Joi.object({
    totalItemsNum: Joi
      .number()
      .min(0)
      .required(),
    skip: Joi
      .number()
      .when('totalItemsNum', [
        {
          is: 0, 
          then: Joi
            .number()
            .optional()
            .empty(Joi.number())
            .default(0)
        },
        {
          is: Joi.number().equal(Joi.ref('skip')), 
          then: Joi
            .number()
            .optional()
            .empty(Joi.number())
            .default((parent) => parent.totalItemsNum - 1)
        },
        {
          is: Joi.number().less(Joi.ref('skip')), 
          then: Joi
            .number()
            .optional()
            .empty(Joi.number())
            .default((parent) => parent.totalItemsNum - 1)
        },
      ]).required(),
    limit: Joi
      .number()
      .default(10)
  })
```

However, I have the impression that this code can be simplified. For instance, I'm always setting the `skip` as optional, to then set any number value to be recognized as an empty value with the `empty(Joi.number())`, to finally use `default()` to force the value I desire.

1. Is there a way to use Joi to reassign a value instead of using Joi.default()?
2. Is there a way to check in the same object if `skip` is greater or equal to `totalItemsNum`?

Comment: did you find any solution?